# Can I upload duotone custom icons to my kit on Font Awesome?

Tags: web-development, fonts, icon

I have created a custom duotone icon and I want to upload it to Font Awesome. Can you do that with the pro plan? Are only solid colors permitted?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it looks like no. According to their Valid SVG requirements, the svg can only have "One `path` element". Since duotone icons use multiple paths to differentiate the two tones (primary and secondary), it seems like we're stuck with 1 color for now. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-kits/prepping-icons-for-upload#valid-svgs

Answer (score 1):

Custom icon upload feature does **not** support the **duotone** style just yet. Checked with FA support just today.